# Stripe Portal url not secure Python

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm working on a Django application integrated with Stripe, and I'm facing a security issue related to user subscription management through the Stripe portal. Currently, I provide a simple link for users with subscriptions to access the portal. However, I've noticed that if I copy the link from the browser tab that the view generate and paste it into a private tab in another browser, the portal loads up, allowing access to someone else's subscription details.

an example of the url generated :
`https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/test_YWNjdF8xSGFuNG5KV3p0WnBRQUJ4LF9POHM5UWlrYlhtM0FadVZmV3NUU3hQFMrgrrgg0HK1DtM1hxe`

This presents a significant security concern since an unauthorized user who obtains the URL could potentially manipulate the billing information of a subscriber.

so my view :

```
def customer_portal(request):
    # Authenticate your user.

    customer_id = request.user.customer.id

    # Create a session.
    session = stripe.billing_portal.Session.create(
      customer=customer_id,
      return_url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/billing/',
    )

    # Directly redirect the user to the portal.
    return redirect(session.url)
```

the link :
`<h4><a href="{% url 'subscriptions:customerPortal' %}">Manage Billing</a></h4>`

the urls :
`path('billing/portal/', customer_portal, name='customerPortal'),`

I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: what is `request` ?

Comment: @D.L request represent the HTTP request made to the server. it contains information about the client's request like headers, cookies and parameters if the user is connected it contains also the user authentication details.

Comment: it looks like the user would have to expose a cryptographic hash, which i presume is generated newly each time. This is just as, if not more secure than the user exposing their password...

Comment: is the hash modified when the session is closed and a new session opened ?

Comment: @D.L Yes each time a new session is created using the customer id and a token generated. But the old session is still available, it expires after an amount of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is a [short lived](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/session#portal_session_object-url) URL and yes, your application would need to make sure to only give the URL to an authenticated customer. Otherwise, you can use a [no-code option](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management/activate-no-code-customer-portal) global link which requires login by email.

Comment: ok, i'm gonna have to add more logic into my view. Thanks a lot @orakaro.